# Identification of harbor and ships

Tags: world-war-two, identification, ships, german

[image][image]Identification of port and country. Identification of ships. WWII era, from a German Kriegsmarine album

Comment: Some more context would be useful. As the question stands, it is basically asking the community to find a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Do you know ***anything*** else about the picture? Harbour identification will require matching up the lighthouse - but there are a few thousand lighthouses (and mole lights) in Europe ([directory](https://www.ibiblio.org/lighthouse/index.htm). I have searched through the **Brittany: Finistère: North** and noted some similar features as here, but nothing that could be a match.

Comment: No other information. I thought the lighthouse distinctive enough that someone might recognize it.

Comment: Could the vessel on the right  be the _Horst Wessel_, now the _USCGC Eagle_? (See https://archive.hnsa.org/ships/eagle.htm )

Comment: The first photo on https://www.treasurebunker.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1335-photos-kiel-harbour-1920s30s/ has a lighthouse (if that's what it is) that looks similar to your lighthouse.

Comment: Yep, Kiel is quite likely, across the Kilian bunker: https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=origxorig:format=jpg/path/s55b669acb6b2c3ce/image/ib55c749a8ad118f0/version/1388048764/image.jpg

Comment: [Another angle, also labeled as from Kiel](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ee/17/02/ee1702d8744ca990cc610f5422ac1da2.jpg) I haven't been able to spot this building on Google Earth however, to locate it in Kiel. Neither have I been able to identify it from the Kiel lighthouses in [the directory from Flensburg to Lübeck](https://www.ibiblio.org/lighthouse/deu3.htm)

Comment: Kiel harbor with cruiser Deutschland https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ee/17/02/ee1702d8744ca990cc610f5422ac1da2.jpg

Comment: @kimchilover: The *Horst Wessel* was definitely used as a stationary *office ship* through the war, in Kiel Harbour. She had a few sister ships which were similarly used, the [*Goch Fock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorch_Fock_(1933)) for example in Stralsund.

Answer (score 14):

This is Kiel, before 1958. The signal tower was build in 1912 and dismantled in 1958. It is located at the [Kiellinie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiellinie_(Kiel)) on the Blücherbrücke:

> [image: Datei:Bundesarchiv B 145 Bild-F005906-0001, Kiel, Jachthafen.jpg]

It [had to be torn down as it developed some Pisa-esque characteristics](https://www.kiel.de/de/bildung_wissenschaft/stadtarchiv/erinnerungstage.php?id=232) after the war.

> [image]
>   [54°20'19.3"N, 10°9'30.9"E](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q56054926)

As it was a frequent guest at exactly this place, I'm going out on a limb and make a wild guess to say the ship was probably the Gorch Fock:

> [image]
>   (src: [Blücherbrücke](http://kiel-wiki.de/Bl%C3%BCcherbr%C3%BCcke))

Note that the ship currently named so was only build in 1958. The [predecessor is from 1933](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorch_Fock_(1933)).

> [image]
>
> [image: https://img.oldthing.net/7580/15857211/0/n/4996063/AK-Kiel-Signalturm-mit-Hafen-und-Bluecherbruecke.jpg] [image] ([src](https://www.akpool.de/ansichtskarten/27293836-ansichtskarte-postkarte-kiel-in-schleswig-holstein-signalturm-mit-hafen-u-bluecherbruecke-dreimaster-kriegsschiff)) Note that the last two [pictures](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/1xgAAOSwR5dXQ2CR/s-l1600.jpg) are [dated "ca 1936"](https://www.ebay.de/itm/swAK-KIel-Signalturm-m-Blucherbrucke-Hafen-ca-1936-neu/352692811634?hash=item521e213772:g:1xgAAOSwR5dXQ2CR).

If it is the first Gorch Fock, then this would date the photo [to 1942–1944, when it was stationed at Kiel (according to an unsourced Wikipedia entry,](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorch_Fock_(Schiff,_1933)) or [an history-oriented newspaper](http://www.doceri.de/archiv/69gorch.html) but [sources seem a bit murky on details](https://www.gorchfock.de/index.php/gorch-fock/informationen)), afterwards being transferred to Stralsund while she was [again in sea-going service](https://www.marine.de/portal/a/marine/start/ueberuns/einheiten/hilfsfahrzeuge/gorchfock/ueber/historie/schwesterschiffe/gorchfocki/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zinSx8QnyMLI2MfNwMHA08XV39PExNPT38LYz1wwkpiAJKG-AAjgb6wSmp-pFAM8xxmuFvph-sH6UflZVYllihV5BfVJKTWqKXmAxyoX5kRmJeSk5qQH6yI0SgIDei3KDcUREAtYvl_A!!/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/#Z7_B8LTL2922LF0A0IEENH55IHOO6).

A print dated 1942 [is sold as](https://www.amazon.de/Hindenburgufer-Vert%C3%A4ut-vertr%C3%A4umt-Signalturm-Kieler/dp/B00A9VWBAW)

> [image]
>   Am Hindenburgufer / Vertäut und verträumt liegt Gorch Fock am Signalturm (Kiel und die Kieler Förde) - historischer Fotodruck / Kupfertiefdruck - 1942

As the slightly later built sister ships look quite similar, the ship in the orignal foto may also be the [Horst Wessel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_(Schiff)) or [Albert Leo Schlageter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagres_(Schiff,_1938)).

As it happens, for example the Horst Wessel was [at least in 1943 also in Kiel](https://books.google.com/books?id=CkoxN6ZSjm8C&lpg=PP4&ots=FdbGceTRe4&pg=PA164) and also seems to prefer anchoring a Blücherbridge when in Kiel and was by 1944 in Stralsund, where it also was in 1941….

> [image]

Since these ships are so similar and details on the original fotos – whether pictoria or regarding date – are still not enough – and well, yeah, ships can move, a lot – for me it seems undecidable which one of the three most probable candidates exactly this is.

Plus, the perspective of the original photo doesn't even rule out that two of these ships were moored there at the same time:

> [image]
>   <sup>[src: Photo's Kiel Harbour 1920s/30s](https://www.treasurebunker.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1335-photos-kiel-harbour-1920s30s/)</sup>

Or all three:

> [image]
>   <sup>[src](https://www.ebay.de/itm/254176738285)</sup>

Data for the ships, according to German Wikipedia:

> ```
>        Gorch Fock  Horst Wessel  Albert Leo Schlageter
> Length 82,1 m      89            89
> Masts   3           3             3
> Sails  23          23            23
> ```

Concerning the sail plan, most pictures of Gorch Fock in the 30s do show a 2 sails on the mizzen mast, while the other two ships have three, but it's unclear whether or when a re-fitting might have taken place. The current state of the Gorch Fock shows another difference there:

> [image]

And by 1940 it seems that the aft-rigging was altered from 2 to 3 sails:

> [image: https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/183847853222_/3Foto-mit-Segelschiff-Gorch-Fock-der-Kriegsmarine.jpg]

That would point in summary to any one of the three German Gorch-Fock-class ships, dated by flag flown in original picture to after 1935 and obviously before May 1945.

For comparison, pictures of all three ships:

> a[image: Horst Wessel] 
>   b[image: Schlageter and Gorch Fock] 
>   c[image: Schlageter] 
>   d[image: Sagres today] 
>   e[image: Gorch Fock today] 
>   f[image: USCGC Eagle (WIX-327)]

<sup>a: Horst Wessel;  b: Schlageter and Gorch Fock;  c: Schlageter; d: Sagres today; e: Gorch Fock today;  f: USCGC Eagle</sup>

---

Further hints: there seems to be a coastal vessel and an early u-boat type to the left of the sailor. The two warships in the distance is another possible clue, but too hard to make out all. The presence of a launch type small boat *("Barkasse"; [modern version](https://www.sfk-kiel.de/de/faehrlinien/foerde/))* for private mass amusements or personal transport from A to B across the bay. Both types of transport should be much rarer [after July 1944](http://spurensuchesh.de/luftkrieg/) when allied air raids hit the place and eastern landing piers.

In the centre of the picture might hint at a date somewhat before 1945 when things got tight and the clothing of all the sailors visible might shift the latest date a few weeks before the end of 1944 as well, when things got cold.

Comment: The [Gorch Fock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorch_Fock_(1933)#Gorch_Fock) was "*a stationary office ship in Stralsund*" during the Second World War, as was [Horst Wessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USCGC_Eagle_(WIX-327)). Perhaps one of the sister ships was used similarly in Kiel. Nice work tracking down the lighthouse.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens According to deWP it was mainly stationary in Kiel before going to Stralsund. But that I'll have try to check with better sources.

Comment: That is certainly the type of error (which sister ship was where) that might slip into Wikipedia. It strikes me as most likely that the various sister ships were in different harbours through the war, rather than the same one.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Hm. After locating images showing GorchFock firmly in Kiel at that place, I start wondering whether the bull's eye configuration might instead point towards HorstWessel or Schlageter? How to tell them aprt, being so similar.

Comment: It will probably be necessary to track down the Kriegsmarine records to know, definitively, which ship was where, when.

Comment: The [log books of the Horst Wessel for 1936-46 (in German)](https://www.archives.gov/research/guide-fed-records/groups/026.html) (search for "*Horst Wessel*") are somewhere in the Washington area - as it was taken as a prize of war and re-assigned as the USCG cutter Eagle.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Darned. Exactly these seem not to be online? But well, I found evidence for Wessel being in Stralsund, Kiel, Stralsund anyway.  Unless someone spots a telltale sign in the OP pic or we get a date for it, I guess this will be a dead end anyway?

Comment: Picture 4  (with the stern view of the 1933 Gorch Fock) shows only one gaff on the mizzen mast, while the OP's picture shows 2, as do most of the other pix of barks of this class.

Comment: @kimchilover Do you still see this diff [here](https://scontent.ftxl2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p526x296/13346976_1123892594320754_4774618434697469879_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_oc=AQkoZ9jPaVL5kseui8W0oo5CdHwj8Ab8ouL07bgjYbzE9SBw72i6YYPVLSUktInVNZs&_nc_ht=scontent.ftxl2-1.fna&oh=aea80af4d29dfdd5fc0b5861eee786e8&oe=5D7A1561)

Comment: @LangLangC  Of course not, not from that camera angle.    Do you have shots of the back ends of the vessels?

Comment: @kimchilover Currently I do not have detailed shots from the 40s, but think that that rigging might change too easily anyway. Why were the others with 3, because 2 proved bad? So why not adapt GF at some time? Do you see another telltale sign that's less easily changed than a feature present in early 30s that might be altered by 40s?

Comment: I think the  evidence is compatible with the barque being any of the GF sisters. The flag on the original picture makes it no earlier than 1935.

Comment: New scan at 1200 dpi.

Comment: I believe that "*launch type small boat for private mass amusements*" is actually just a ferry. There are no bridges across the fjord, so it is probably kept open with icebreakers for 12-month use. Also - through the fore-rigging of the tall-ship on right, just above lifeboat, I believe I can see another tall-ship - ***in full sail***. That would really nail down the date with two ships present, and at least one in use for training not office.